# Changing left side navigation using php for different pages

Tags: php, navigation

I want to show different - different left side navigations menu for different - different pages in my php site. so i have created some navigation.php file and i am calling them directly in my webpages (like - for home.php navigation should be home_left_side_navigation.php and for other pages other.php and so on....) , is it a good way of doing this work or not?
(I am simply using include() function to add navigation menu)

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div class="left_side_navigation">
        <?php include("includes/cplusplus_left_side_navigation.php") ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is how i am adding different - different navigation menu in my different - different pages.

Comment: add your code pleases ..

Comment: Templating directly with php is has-been. You'd prefer use Smarty or Blade or Twig...

Comment: Can you please explain me little bit more.

Comment: You should explain a little bit more. Add the relevant parts of your code, as RïshïKêsh Kümar has said before.

Comment: See this [link](http://www.sitecrafting.com/blog/top-5-php-template-engines/) for more informations about php template engines. If you want a real answer to your question, you'll have to share the relevant code you're talking about.